# decrementing the tuple values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list which contains service time for various clients, I want to loop through this list and decrement service time each second

```
import time

def mylist():
    active_clients.append((1,20))

    t = list(active_clients)

    print "service time = %s" ,t[0][1]
    print type(t)

    while(t[0][1] > 0):
        old_service_time = t[0][1]
        t[0][1]  = old_service_time -1
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    active_clients = []
    mylist()
```

I know that tuples are immutable hence I used list() for conversion, but why still I am not able to decrement service time values?

Comment: Because you did not construct a list, but a list containing a tuple. Of course that tuple is still immutable.

Comment: Despite your `python-3.x` tag, the `print` statement is appropriate only for Python 2. Please correct either the code or the tag.

Comment: What is the purpose of `t = list(active_clients)` isn't `active_clients` already list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as pointed by @schwobaseggl below is the working code snippet

```
import time

def mylist():
    active_clients.append((1,20))

    t = list(map(list, active_clients))



    while(t[0][1] > 0):

        print "service time =", t[0][1]
        t[0][1] = t[0][1] - 1
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    active_clients = []
    mylist()
```

Answer (score 3):

The elements of your list are still tuples, though. Try:

```
t = list(map(list, active_clients))
```

This makes sure that both `t` and its elements are, in fact, `lists` and mutable.